# Magento creating invoice redirect to wrong url

Tags: magento

When I create an invoice from the order in the backend, this on this url:

```
http://www.site.com/index.php/safe/sales_order_invoice/new/order_id/4372/
```

But when the Invoice is about to be created it goes to:

```
http://www.site.com/shop/safe/sales_order/view/order_id/4372/
```

You see the (Shop), which is mostly correct because the storefront is named that(We had 2 storefronts once) If I remove the (Shop) part from the url, I'm getting back to the correct page and it shows that the invoice was correctly created. This only happens from the Order itself. If I use Mass action to create invoices from the orders list, it's not giving me any problems.

Comment: this only happens from the ... what? Sames question to you: Cache is cleared?

Comment: I've added the rest of the text, something went wrong when posting.
I've cleared sessions and cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else has the problem (Using multi stores)

Please check your database, core_config_data and see if web/secure/base_url etc. is redirecting to the right path. And make sure to check that it's doing so for the right store ID that is giving you the trouble.

My problem was that the secure path for one of my stores, was ruining it.

All works fine now!